# How to pass Array[Long] ids into Aerospike Record UDF?

Tags: arrays, lua, udf, aerospike

I store many sub records as Map in the same top record, now I need remove some sub records according to passing keys, I plan to use UDF to implement it. When I invoked from Java, the log shows the length is 0. Why? and how to correct this? Thanks!

In Java =>

```
val ids = Array(1,2,3)
Value.get(ids)
```

In Lua UDF =>

```
function remove_keys(rec, binName, rmkeys)

    info("Value(%s) valType(%s)",  tostring(rec), type(rec));
    info("Value(%s) valType(%s)",  tostring(binName), type(binName));
    info("Value(%s) valType(%s)",  tostring(rmkeys), type(rmkeys));

    info("BinName(%s)", binName)
    info("len(%s)", tostring(#rmkeys))
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String binName = "binName";
List<Value> rmKeys = new ArrayList<Value>();
rmKeys.add(Value.get("key1"));

client.execute(policy, key, packageName, "remove_keys", Value.get(binName), Value.get(rmKeys));
```